# Is it possible to installing tomcat in different directory and keeping web application in other directory

Tags: java, tomcat

I don't know I am asking correct question or not (may be its silly).

Suppose I am having tomcat installed on dir `c:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\..` with some web applications in it and now I wanted to deploy another application `(war)` but I don't want to keep my web application on location `c:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\webppas\{myapplicationDir}` I wanted to deploy on suppose `D:\{applicationDir}`

Is it possible? If yes then is it there any kind of problem that I gonna face.

Comment: Its possible, i've seen it implemented that way, but not sure how though.. i've only seen that hey have to create a configuration file within conf/Catalina/localhost to set the real directory there.. sorry i couldnt help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very possible, you can define the base in the configuration file for each webapp. These configuration files for you would be located in the `c:\Apache\Tomcat 7.0\conf\Catalina\localhost` directory. The config file should be named `{APP_NAME}.xml`, so you might have `ROOT.xml`

Heres what one of mine looks like for a project I have in Eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\workdir\test\dev\web\src\main\webapp" path="/"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
its all about the container and context.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html 
I dont think there should be problems with this approach infact it is better to move out things from server.xml.